# Shell Script to extract two zip folders

Tags: shell

I have 2 zip folder at a particular location. Let it be A.zip & B.zip. I want to extract these two folders and place it in the same location. How can it be done?
I have tried the below script but its not working.

```
   set -a filename A.zip B.zip      
   source_dir=/app/webmcore1/Test       
   target_dir=/app/webmcore1/Test       
   for i in $filename[*]       
   do  
        unzip $source_dir/$filename[$i];  
   done
```

Please suggest and help

Comment: Did you try `cd $target_dir`? What does "it's not working" mean, exactly. What behavior are you seeing - and what did you want to see?

Comment: The problem is that there are many sub folders inside both A & B. After running this script i am getting the output which shows all subfolders in the target location. But my requirement is that the subfolder should remain inside A & B only . I want A.zip becomes A at the same location & B.zip becomes B. Moreover i would like to mention that A & B are same zip folder but different versions , so the file content & folder structure is same, there will be just few minor changes in few of the xml files.

Comment: May I suggest that you create a more complete example - maybe with 3 files in `A.zip`, 3 files in `B.zip`. Tell us the directory structure you have: where are A and B stored, where do you want to extract them, what do you want to happen if files in A and B have the same name, what about subfolders?... "After both archives are extracted the directory should look like this: ...".  Right now you are asking us to read your mind and that is not a good approach to problem solving.

Comment: There are two similar zip folders but with different versions.
[webmcore1@ryelxjdwmc Test]$ pwd
/app/webmcore1/Test
[webmcore1@ryelxjdwmc Test]$ ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmcore1 webm 130381 Sep 30 14:44 CORE_MES_Item_Master_E1_MES_v13_4.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 webmcore1 webm 132004 Jan 31 13:06 CORE_MES_Item_Master_E1_MES_v14_0.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 webmcore1 webm    570 Feb 12 04:18 extract.sh

Comment: Inside CORE_MES_Item_Master_E1_MES_v13_4 there are below folders
drwxrwxr-x 5 webmcore1 webm   4096 Feb 12 04:27 code
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Sep 30 14:44 config
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Sep 30 14:44 doc
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Sep 30 14:44 lib
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webmcore1 webm    400 Sep 30 14:44 manifest.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webmcore1 webm    769 Sep 30 14:44 manifest.rel
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webmcore1 webm    400 Sep 30 14:44 manifest.v3
drwxrwxr-x 3 webmcore1 webm   4096 Feb 12 04:27 ns
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Feb 12 04:27 pub

Comment: When i am using the script or just unzip CORE_MES_Item_Master_E1_MES_v13_4.zip command i am getting the result as at /app/webmcore1/Test :-
drwxrwxr-x 5 webmcore1 webm   4096 Feb 12 04:27 code
-rwxr-xr-x 1 webmcore1 webm    451 Feb 12 03:55 compare.sh
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Sep 30 14:44 config
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Sep 30 14:44 doc
drwxrwxr-x 2 webmcore1 webm   4096 Sep 30 14:44 lib
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webmcore1 webm    400 Sep 30 14:44 manifest.bak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webmcore1 webm    769 Sep 30 14:44 manifest.rel
-rw-rw-r-- 1 webmcore1 webm    400 Sep 30 14:44 manifest.v3

Comment: But my requirement is after the using the unzip command it should come as, at the same loaction /app/webmcore1/Test
CORE_MES_Item_Master_E1_MES_v13_4
CORE_MES_Item_Master_E1_MES_v14_0
and if i click on the above two folders i shuold be able to see all the sub folders as mentioned above
I want to unzip both the folders at the location /app/webmcore1/Test

Comment: Please put this information in your question (by "editing" it) - it will be much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `declare -a arr=(...)` to declare an array.

You can use this script:

```
declare -a filename=("A.zip" "B.zip")
source_dir="/app/webmcore1/Test"
target_dir="/app/webmcore1/Test"

for i in "${filename[@]}"     
do  
    unzip "$source_dir/$i" 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply anubhava. But the problem is that there are many sub folders inside both A & B. After running this script i am getting the output which shows all subfolders in the target location. But my requirement is that the subfolder should remain inside A & B only . I want A.zip becomes A at the same location & B.zip becomes B. Moreover i would like to mention that A & B are same zip folder but different versions , so the file content & folder structure is same, there will be just few minor changes in few of the xml files.

Comment: I am unable to understand your comment. Can you edit your question and clarify the problem by some examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
filename="A.zip B.zip"
source_dir=/app/webmcore1/Test       
for i in $filename
do  
    unzip "$source_dir/$i";
done
```